# Get TeamCity running on Docker

Tags: docker, teamcity

I'm brand new to both TeamCity and Docker. I'm struggling to get a Docker container with TeamCity running and usable on my local machine. I've tried several things, to no avail:

I installed Docker for Mac per instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/). I then tried to run the following command, documented [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/jetbrains/teamcity-server/), for setting up teamcity in docker:

```
    docker run -it --name teamcity-server-instance \
    -v c:\docker\data:/data/teamcity_server/datadir \
    -v c:\docker\logs:/opt/teamcity/logs \
    -p 8111:8111 \
    jetbrains/teamcity-server
```

That returned the following error: docker: Error response from daemon: Invalid bind mount spec "c:dockerdata:/data/teamcity_server/datadir": invalid mode: /data/teamcity_server/datadir.

Taking a different tack, I tried to follow the instructions [here](https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2016/03/22/ci-with-teamcity-and-docker/) - I tried running the following command:

```
    docker run -it --name teamcity -p 8111:8111 sjoerdmulder/teamcity
```

The terminal indicated that it was starting up a web server, but I can't browse to it at localhost, nor at localhost:8111 (error ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED without the port, and ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with the port).

Since the website with the docker run command says to install Docker via Docker Toolbox, I then installed that at the location they pointed to ([here](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox)). I then tried the

```
    docker-machine ip default
```

command they suggested, but it didn't work, error "Host does not exist: "default"". That makes sense, since the website said the "default" vm would be created by running Docker Quickstart and I didn't do that, but they don't provide any link to Docker Quickstart, so I don't know what they are talking about.

To try to get the IP address the container was running on, I tried this command

```
    docker inspect --format='{{.Name}} - {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $(docker ps -aq)
```

That listed the names of the running containers, each followed by a hyphen, then nothing. I also tried

```
    docker ps -a
```

That listed running contaners also, but didn't give the IP. Also, the port is blank, and the status says "exited (130) 4 minutes ago", so it doesn't seem like the container stayed alive after starting.

I also tried again with port 80, hoping that would make the site show at localhost:

```
    docker run -it --name teamcity2 -p 80:80 sjoerdmulder/teamcity
```

So at this point, I'm completely puzzled and blocked - I can't start the server at all following the instructions on hub.docker.com, and I can't figure out how to browse to the site that does start up with the other instructions.

I'll be very grateful for any assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JetBrains now provides [official docker images](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2016/06/teamcity-on-docker-hub-its-official-now/) for TeamCity. I would recommend starting with those.

The example command in their TeamCity [server](https://hub.docker.com/r/jetbrains/teamcity-server/) image looks like this

```
docker run -it --name teamcity-server-instance  \
    -v <path to data directory>:/data/teamcity_server/datadir \
    -v <path to logs directory>:/opt/teamcity/logs  \
    -p <port on host>:8111 \
    jetbrains/teamcity-server
```

That looks a lot like your first attempt. However, `c:\docker\data` is a Windows file path. You said you're running this on a mac, so that's definitely not going to work.

Once TeamCity starts, it should be available on port 8111. That's what `-p 8111:8111` part of the command does. It maps port 8111 on your machine to port 8111 in the VM Docker for Mac creates to run your containers. `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` could be caused by several things. Two most likely possibilities are

1. TeamCity could take a little while to start up and maybe you didn't give it enough time. Solution is to wait.
2. `-it` would start the TeamCity container in interactive mode. If you exit out of the terminal window where you ran the command, the container will also probably terminate and will be inaccessible. Solution is to not close the window or run the container in [detached](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/detached-vs-foreground) mode.

---

There is a good overview of the differences between Docker for Mac and Docker Toolbox here: [Docker for Mac vs. Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/). You don't need both, and for most cases you'll want to use Docker for Mac for testing stuff out locally.

Comment: Thank you! I am new to Mac also and had forgotten that the paths are specified differently. It's working great now on port 8111!

Comment: Great, did it work correctly with mapped paths or did you have to change anything else?

Comment: I just had to change the paths in the command I had posted originally, and then it worked. Thanks!